# jquery spritefy pause and restart

Tags: jquery, sprite, setinterval

I'm useing this plugin: http://www.spritely.net/
Can anyone tell me why the variable $sprite doesn't re-execute?

```
function animate_header() {
    var $sprite = $('#header') 
        .sprite({
            fps: 30, 
            no_of_frames: 4,
            // the following are optional: new in version 0.6...
            start_at_frame: 1,
            rewind: false,
            on_last_frame: function(obj) {
                // you could stop the sprite here with, e.g.
                obj.spStop();
            }
        })
        .active();
}
var init = setInterval("animate_header()", 1000);
```

I also tried this:

```
function animate_header() {
    $('#header') 
        .sprite({
            fps: 30, 
            no_of_frames: 4,
            // the following are optional: new in version 0.6...
            start_at_frame: 1,
            rewind: false,
            on_last_frame: function(obj) {
                // you could stop the sprite here with, e.g.
                obj.spStop();
            }
        })
        .active();
}
var init = setInterval("animate_header()", 1000);
```

The function itself executes every second. But the sprite doesn't.

Comment: What's .active()? I don't see it as a method of spritely (or is a jQuery function?).

Comment: Sorry, I see it. Did you try calling .destroy() on it and then rerunning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this. Wich worked as I wanted.

```
function loop() {

  $('#bird').sprite({fps: 7,  no_of_frames: 4, play_frames: 4});

           var t = setTimeout(function(){
            loop()
           }, 2000);
       }
       loop()
```

Thanks for any replies though.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me.  I set the options first, then I looped it with the spStart function.

```
$('#header') 
    .sprite({
        fps: 30, 
        no_of_frames: 4,
        start_at_frame: 1,
        rewind: false,
        on_last_frame: function(obj) {
            // you could stop the sprite here with, e.g.
            obj.spStop();
        }
    });

setInterval ( "$('#header').spStart()", 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that might happen to stumble on this, use

```
.destroy()
```

The animation seems to break after running a few times every other way, but destroy fixes it :)

Comment: Really useful, just try to explain its usage a little bit so others will be able to use it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `.active();` with `.spStart();` at the end of your code.

Looks like `obj.spStop()` that is called on last frame just kills animation dead and it needs a jump start to get it going...
Worked for me :)